# Angular2 router not working with matrix url notation

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm having trouble with the newest angular2 router. In my app I navigate to a route with optional parameters and they are displayed in Matrix Url Notation like http://localhost:3000/route;id=167

that works fine from router links. However, if I hit refresh or paste these urls I always get "Cannot match any routes". Is this format still supported or is there some way I need to configure the routes for optional parameters?

I'm defining my route as:

```
 {path:'route', component: RouteComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]}
```

I have `<base href="/"> inside <head>`. Any other things I could be missing?

Comment: It should work. Can you please provide more information? Does the server you're using support HTML5 pushState? Have you tried with `HashLocationStrategy`?

Comment: I'm using nginx in production and developing using npm's lite server. This used to work for me, but I'm not sure which release broke it, so I think the servers are set up correctly. I just tried providing HashLocationStrategy and that changed nothing. I think I'm just going to move away from matrix url notation since so few examples are supporting it.

Comment: nginx needs some rewrite rule. There are answered questions. I'm only on the phone ...